# BlueTooth + поворот экрана на Android

Tags: android, java, bluetooth

Возникла такая проблема.
Запускаю приложение. Происходит скан на близлежащие ВТ-устройства. Все прекрасно - находятся, добавляются в список, если экран повернуть, то все остается на месте. Проблема в том, что если отключить ВТ и повернуть экран, то приложение слетает. Я не могу разобраться, почему так происходит. Может кто-нибудь посмотрит [проект](http://ifolder.ru/29593251) и скажет, что не так?

Answer (score 3):

При повороте экрана активити закрывается и открывается заново с уже новыми параметрами. В промежутке между этим вызывается метод `Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle instanceState)`. Вам надо сохранить данные активити в `Bundle instanceState`. Далее при создании `Activity` этот самый `Bundle` передается в `Activity.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` - так что вы можете восстановить состояние `Activity` перед поворотом.

Очевидно, вы не сохраняете свое состояние при повороте и из-за этого и происходит некий крэш.

Comment: Да сохраняю я все. Я же написал - если БТ не отключать в ходе работы программы, то хоть заповорачивайся - все отлажено. Если же перед поворотом отключить БТ, то прога вылетает. Я же ведь не просто так проект выложил. Кода там мало (для проекта) и, думаю, все понятно. Гуру дроида, по-моему, должны за несколько минут сообразить, в чем проблема.

Comment: Поставь проверку mBluetoothAdapter на null везде где можно - особливо в onSaveInstanceState - перед cancelDiscovery